# SWI Prolog interpret/compile from command line

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am using Windows, and i want to interpret/compile a prolog file with cmd, is any method to do that?. The purpose is to make a shell to the interpreter/compiler prolog to a file like:

```
gplc -output C:\a.output -input C:\a.pl
```

And in the output file to be the answers for my goals. I had read some documentation for `swi-prolog.com` and I didn't find.

I had tried with GNU Prolog(and it raise me an error for gcc)

I have this file `D:\a.pl`

```
mouther(john).
jiji(ok).

?- jiji(ok).
```

in CMD I run `swipl -s D:\a.pl -o D:\a2.txt`

And I want in a2 the answers for my goals, but it isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot check it right now but you could start out with something like

```
swipl -s file.pl -g "mygoal(3,foo)." -t halt.
```

This would consult `file.pl`, run goal `mygoal(3,foo)` and then halt the interpreter without entering interactive mode. Check the command line options for more info.

Comment: I installed SWI-Prolog on Windows 10, but the `swipl` command still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @AndersonGreen The Windows installer for SWI-Prolog doesn't modify your PATH variable, but you still have the `swipl.exe` executable. Either call it fully qualified, like `"C:\Program Files\swipl\bin\swipl.exe"`, or add the corresponding `bin` path to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Hey @ThomasH I tried this, but it still goes into the interactive mode. If I remove one of the files I'm loading then I can see the error of the goal not existing. It seems that if it works, it goes into the swipl terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: @ThomasH I'm running `swipl -s pairs.pro triangular.pro -g "customRatio(A,B,C, 1.05, ResultRatio)." -t halt.`

Comment: @bitoiu No, sorry, maybe the semantics of the command line args have changed since?!

Comment: @bitoiu Looking a recent swipl's (7.6.3) command line help, it seems you still can only provide a single .pro file with `-s`, not two.

Comment: @ThomasH thanks, I was reducing the problem until I got it. I know require one file and include the other. Now I've been stuck on how to produce output. The pairs.pro is generated from a Node.JS file, and I need to be able to run and extract all the goals output to process further. I should open a new question on that, currently googling the hell out of it :)